# C - OR in IF statements not working has I want

Tags: c, if-statement

I've started learning C really recently in school, and I'm having a problem which I can't see where's the mistake.
I'm currently learning functions, and I have to develop a program that calculates the area of some geometric shapes with multiple functions. That's not going so well, but the problem I have is related with OR in IF statements. I'm trying to make the user select specific charecters, otherwise it will show "Invalid option, try again". The problem is that even if the users chooses the correct chars, the "warning" will show.
Sorry for bad english.

```
        int menu()
        {
            char opc;

        do
            {
                printf("Areas\n");
                printf("\nTriangle (nr):  \t\t\tRectangle (nr):  \n");
                printf("\nCircle (nr):  \t\t\t\tSquare (nr):  ");
                printf("\n\n\t\tOPIONS");
                printf("\n\n\t(T)riangle\n\t(R)ectangle\n\t(S)quare\n\t(C)ircle\n\t(E)nd\n\n");
                scanf(" %c", &opc);
                if((opc!='t') || (opc != 'c') || (opc != 'r') || (opc != 's') || (opc !='e'))
                   {
                        printf("\nInvalid option, try again\n");
                   }
            }
        while(opc!='e');
            return opc;

       }
```

Comment: Because you need `&&` there. Spell out loud your condition and see if it makes sense.

Comment: `(opc!='t') || (opc != 'c') || (opc != 'r') || (opc != 's') || (opc !='e')` is **always** true because `opc` can only have one value, so it must be unequal to at least four of those five values it's compared to.

Comment: Also google "de morgan" (no joke)

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
if((opc!='t') && (opc != 'c') && (opc != 'r') && (opc != 's') && (opc !='e'))
```

In your code, `opc` can have only one value always at least 5 conditions will be `true`. If one of the conditions is `true`, the whole expression is `true`. So it is always the `true` despite the value of `opt`

Answer (score 0):

't'!='c', 'c'!='r' etc so no letter is correct - you meet the condition for all letters.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use && instead of || .because if the first condition is true ,I mean user input a character other than 't' ,compiler won't check next condition and whole expression will get true.